# Python parser for wrok with url

Tags: python, html, parsing, url, python-requests

I tried to write a python program that opens a page in the browser and there, through the element         code, it opens the code (with f12, not ctrl+U) and goes through all the "span" that are in this code, but I have not found how to do it, maybe here who knows how to do it?

P.S. based on what I have written, I assume that not through this line:
BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
because it is a replacement for ctrl+u All I could do, but this is just an unnecessary

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://sites_url'

response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    all_text = ''

    span_elements = soup.find_all('span')
    for span in span_elements:
        text = span.get_text()
        all_text += text + ' ' 
    all_text = all_text.strip()

    print('span:', all_text)
else:
    print('cant open.')`
```

P.S.2.0
u can see youtube has 304 spans, and i want my prog to seek all 304 positions, but if u use it now prog will be find in ctrl+u
[if u press ctrl+u](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE1Z1.png)
[if u press f12, not ctrl + u](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMo5p.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry could you please explain your problem more clearly? Accroding to my test I think your code can run well...

My test:
target html:

```
<span>this is text</span>
<span>this is text2</span>
```

result:

span: this is text this is text2

--edit in 2023.10.17

sry for late reply. I understand your problem now. This is because html elements that you see are rendered by your browser before but if you use curl or python requests to visit you can only get source code. (You can search google to understand how your browser render html with source code)

To solve this problem, you can use python **selenium** package. This is a python package that is used for emulating the browser. By using this you can get html rendered by browser.

Comment: I can explain just try my code on many sites like youtube for example and my program write nothing because if u press ctrl+u u find code and when you press ctrl+f u will see 1 span and his was empty, but i want my program to search span in code of html page which i can open with f12, just try to open with f12 and ctrl+u that 2 different codes

Comment: Could u give a more detailed example with some code and result images?

Comment: now u can see 2 photos like u want

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).